# MBP Late 2013 A1502 High fan usage and kernel_task at 300%, mobo replaced no luck

Tags: macbook-pro

My computer is super laggy after my fiancee spilled water on it. I originally bought a new motherboard but still seeing the same behavior. Hardware diagnostics show PFM006 and PPN001. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks for looking.

Comment: new mobo needs SMC reset

Comment: Have you checked for malware and/or viruses?

Comment: PFM006 - System Management Controller and PPN001 Power Management System. https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/491642/MacBook+Pro+late+2013+13”+PPN001+PFM006+fan+at+full+speed+and+slow

Answer (score 1):

I found a thermal sensor under the trackpad that was returning a bad temperature reading. This throttled the CPU and forced the fan to 100%. Bought a new palm rest/upper case assembly and will update if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue. After replace track pad is everything became normal.

Comment: This resolved my issue, yes. When you run hardware diagnostics what codes are returned? Send me a message and I'll see if I can help out since the question answers aren't the place for this kind of stuff. We can edit later with additional information for anyone else.